# React JS: Design an app with controls to move an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am a newbie to React JS and trying to make a simple application with directional controls to move an object up down left right. I plan to create 2 components `<Object />` and `<Controls />` (consisting 4 buttons) with event handlers to update `position state` of the `<Object />` component. But I encounter 2 problems:

- Where to store the `position state`? As I understand, flux architecture doesn't allow the `<Controls />` component to update `<Object />` component state.
- How to write a single event handler to serve 4 similar buttons (up, down, left, right)? It's ok to write 4 separate functions but is it possible to use only one?

Could you advise the right way to approach the above 2 questions?

Many thanks!
mockup: control buttons to move objects:

[image: mockup: control buttons to move objects]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to organise the events and state:
https://jsfiddle.net/zL4vmq0L/

As you can see, there's an `App` component that holds all the state and passes the state changing function, `move`, into the `Controls` component via `props`.

There are multiple libraries to manage the app's state, like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Filipe, that's excellent. Can I ask in case I have several components need to update each other state, the pattern is always to store the `state` at parent component and passing them down to the children via `props`?

Comment: Regarding the question 2, is it common with react js that the event handler identify which button is clicked using, for example, `event.target`, `refs`, or `key`? Or is there any other way to id parameter to event handler functions?

Comment: If you take a look at redux, the state is stored at the very root of the application; so yes, that the current status quo of how to organise the data.  


About your second question, you can identify events like that, however from my experience it's easier to test and re-use functions if they don't depend on the event object and receive normal arguments instead.

Comment: thanks a million @Fillipe, I learnt a lot about React style via your explanation